# What should I choose between rollbackfor in exception and runtimeException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

When I use transaction in Exception, I use @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class).

But, When I use RuntimeException, I use @Transactional.

What should I choose between rollbackfor in exception and runtimeException?

ex) 
public class BadRequestException extends Exception
-> public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring provides inbuilt support to rollback to `RuntimeException` same as EJB. Though, adding rollback support for Application Exception (checked Exception) you can define like this.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = BadRequestException.class)
```

**Spring documentation** : "While the Spring default behavior for declarative transaction management follows EJB convention (roll back is automatic only on unchecked exceptions), it is often useful to customize this". [source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative)